# Rendering a layout using an example as guide

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this component that renders a menu:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

import Intro from './Intro'
import Houses from './Houses'
import PortfolioPage from './PortfolioPage'
import Cronology from './Cronology'

var data = require('./db.json');

class PortfolioMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      portfolioClass: "",
      interiors: [],
      furnitures: [],
      studies: [],
      houses: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      interiors: data.interiors[0],
      furnitures: data.furnitures[0],
      studies: data.studies[0],
      houses: data.houses
    })
  }        
  render() {      
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="wrapper-portfolio">
              <Route exact path='/portfolio' render={() => <Intro />} />
              <Route exact path='/portfolio/casas' render={() => <Houses data={this.state.houses}/>} />
              <Route exact path='/portfolio/interiores' render={() => <PortfolioPage data={this.state.interiors}/>} />
              <Route exact path='/portfolio/moveis' render={() => <PortfolioPage data={this.state.furnitures}/>} />
              <Route exact path='/portfolio/estudos' render={() => <PortfolioPage data={this.state.studies}/>} />
              <Route exact path='/portfolio/cronologia' render={() => <Cronology />} />
            </div>
            <nav>
              <ul className={`portfolio-menu ${portfolioClass}`}>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" isActive={this.isActive} exact to="/portfolio">• introdução</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/casas">• casas</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/interiores">• interiores</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/moveis">• móveis</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/estudos">• estudos</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/cronologia">• cronologia</NavLink></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>           
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default PortfolioMenu
```

And I would like to do the `<li>` to behave like this example below:

[image]

How can I solve it? I would like to render in this exact way that is showing on this example. Doing this distribution of li's elements. I want to make four blocks on the first row and two on the second.

Comment: Like the example how? Inline blocks? Varying block sizes? What layout library or framework are you using? The question is very broad.

Comment: Im using React and I'm using pure css without any lte

Comment: You need to make an effort before asking. I see no attempt at layout in your question.

Comment: I would use flex if I were you. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/14agh0L9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use pure CSS (as you mentioned in your comment above), you'll want to use [CSS grids](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

If you're open to using a third-party JavaScript library, I'd recommend looking into [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/). Specifically their [Grid](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#grid) component.

Your question makes it look like you're relatively new to front-end development, so I'd recommend the second approach. Material-UI includes many commonly used components that are well tested across multiple browsers. It's a good way to create a nice layout and design without as much headache.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-replace-flexbox/) comparing the two. There are benefits and drawbacks to both.